# How to get the stored object from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable in which I can add users with several attributes like age, name, etc. This works and the users are added to my arraylist and JTable.
Now what I want is when I choose the JTable row, to be able to get the object stored in the user's arrayList so that I can modify or delete them.

Here is the example of my code when I add users to the JTable:

```
private void jButtonAddAUserActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
   User obj=new User();
   obj.setName(jTextFieldName.getText());
   obj.setAdress(jTextFieldAdress.getText());
   obj.setNumCC(Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldNumCC.getText()));
   obj.setTele(Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldTele.getText()));
   obj.setUserName(jTextFieldUserName.getText());
   obj.setPassword(jTextFieldPassword.getText());

   DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel) jTableUsers.getModel();
   model.addRow(new Object[]{
       jTextFieldName.getText(),
       jTextFieldAdress.getText(),
       jTextFieldTele.getText(),
       jTextFieldNumCC.getText(),
       obj.isAdmin
   });

   usersList.add(obj);
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data inserted correctly.");
   jTextFieldName.setText("");
   jTextFieldAdress.setText("");
   jTextFieldNumCC.setText("");
   jTextFieldTele.setText("");
   jTextFieldPassword.setText("");
   jTextFieldUserName.setText("");
}
```

Edit:
Here is the code for removing users already working:

private void jButtonRemoverActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTableInvestidores.getModel();

    User u = userList.get(jTableUsers.getSelectedRow()); 
    userList.remove(u);
    model.removeRow(jTableUsers.getSelectedRow());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data removed.");

}
```

And here is the code for updating user that is still not working, im trying to update it from the jTextFields:

```
private void jButtonUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTableUsers.getModel();
    userList.get(jTableUsers.getSelectedRow());
    model.setValueAt(jTextFieldName.getText(), jTableUsers.getSelectedRow(),0);
    model.setValueAt(jTextFieldAdress.getText(), jTableUsers.getSelectedRow(),1);
    model.setValueAt(jTextFieldPhone.getText(), jTableUsers.getSelectedRow(),2);
    model.setValueAt(jTextFieldNumCC.getText(), jTableUsers.getSelectedRow(),3);
    User u =userList.get(jTableUsers.getSelectedRow());

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data updated.");

}
```

Can anyone please give me some help on this? Thanks!

Comment: `userList.get(table.getSelectedRow());` will result in an user object at the given index. now you can modify the user object and replace the user in your list. afterwards "repaint" your table with the modified data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use something similar to this. sadly you didn't specify how you want to edit the user.

```
User u=userList.get(table.getSelectedRow());  //get user for editing
int location=table.getSelectedRow();  //get location in list to maintain order
userList.remove(u);  //remove selected user to edit variables
//modify user u
userList.add(location,u);  //insert user at previous location in list
model.setRowCount(0);  //reset table model
for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {  //refill table model 
    User u = userList.get(i);  /7get user
    Vector<Object> vhelp = new Vector<>(); //create vector to store the values of the variables from user
    vhelp.add(/*your data*/);  // 1 add per variable that should be displayed in table
    model.addRow(vhelp); //add the data to the table model (fills the table with data)
}
```

your method should look like this:

```
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTableUsers.getModel();
    User u = userList.get(jTableUsers.getSelectedRow());
    int location=jTableUsers.getSelectedRow();
    userList.remove(u);
    u.setName(jTextFieldName.getText());
    u.setAdress(jTextFieldAdress.getText());
    u.setNumCC(Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldNumCC.getText()));
    u.setTele(Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldTele.getText()));
    //u.isAdmin can't tell what this has to be
    userlist.add(location,u);

    model.setRowCount(0);  
    for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {  
        User u = userList.get(i);  
        Vector<Object> vhelp = new Vector<>(); 
        vhelp.add(u.getName()); 
        vhelp.add(u.getAddress());
        vhelp.add(u.getTele());
        vhelp.add(u.getNumCC());
        vhelp.add(u.isAdmin);
        model.addRow(vhelp);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data updated.");
```

Comment: Do need to have all the object(user) atributes in the jTable?im having index out of bounds wen deleting could it be because of it?

Comment: Im getting the error after: User u=userList.get(table.getSelectedRow());

Comment: userList.remove(u);

Comment: Error was index out of bounds , i fixed it, im now trying to understand your code for editing the uses

Comment: i think its fairly simple. first you get the user you want to edit, as well as the location it is in your list. then you remove the user with the old parameters, and add the "new" user with new parameters at the same location, where it was previously. after that you "rebuild" the table with the pretty much exact same data as before, with the difference, that the user you updated has different values as before

Comment: That is exactly what i wanted, but i cant seem to see it in that code :) i will try to implement it maybe it will help me understand.

Comment: Thanks , i could not make it work...Anyway i edit my post with the rest of the code, everything is working but the edit/update user is still not...

Answer (score 1):

> the users are added to my arraylist and JTable.

Don't store the data in two separate places. The data should only be stored in the `TableModel` of the `JTable`.

So you can create a custom "User" object to contain the data about each user. Then you can create a custom `TableModel` to hold "User" object which can be displayed and access by the `JTable`.

> Now what I want is when I choose the JTable row, to be able to get the object stored in the user's arrayList so that I can modify or delete them.

Check out [Table Row Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step by step approach on create the custom `TableModel`. It contains all the methods you need to dynamically add, access and delete objects from the `TableModel`.

Comment: I need to rewrite most of my code for this i think, and i dont know if i can do the same method im doing of having a class with all the data, wich is serialized so that i can later save it to files and objects...but i will give it a try to see were i can get...